# Issue while updating java project from JDK11 to JDK17

Tags: reflection, java-11, java-17, java

I have a java project using jdk11. I need to migrate the project to java 17 but integration tests have started failing. As soon as I upgraded to JDK17 I started getting below error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make private sun.reflect.generics.repository.FieldRepository java.lang.reflect.Field.getGenericInfo() accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang.reflect" to unnamed module @5702b3b1
```

I was also getting error for java.util but that is fixed using below command line code.

I have tried adding the command line options as below but the tests are still failing

```
                <argLine>
                    --illegal-access=permit
                    --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
                    --add-opens java.base/sun.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED
                    --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
                </argLine>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try `--add-opens java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED`

Comment: Or remove the need for such hacks from your code. Otherwise, be prepared for this code to break again in one of the next releases…

Comment: @JoachimSauer Yes, I have tried this but still failing

Answer (score -1):

You can pass your method in to this:

```
public static <T extends AccessibleObject> T forceAccessible(T o) {
    try {
        Field unsafeField = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
        unsafeField.setAccessible(true);
        Unsafe unsafe = (Unsafe) unsafeField.get(null);

        Method m = Class.class.getDeclaredMethod("getDeclaredFields0", boolean.class);
        m.setAccessible(true);
        Field override = ((Field[]) m.invoke(AccessibleObject.class, false))[0];

        if (!o.isAccessible()) {
            try {
                o.setAccessible(true);
            } catch (InaccessibleObjectException e) {
                unsafe.putBoolean(o, unsafe.objectFieldOffset(override), true);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    return o;
}
```